# Adding a list item through JavaScript with window.prompt()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add ordered list items depending on what a user enters in window.prompt(). Is this possible?

Below is my code. Sorry if this is messy, I'm fairly new to this. Any help is appreciated!

```html
 <!DOCTYPE = html>
 <head>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    var test = document.getElementById('list');
    var item1 = window.prompt("Enter first item:");
      if (item1 != null) {
        function listAdd() {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item1));
          list.appendChild(entry);
        }
    }

    var item2 = window.prompt("Enter second item");
      if (item2 != null) {
        function listAdd() {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item2));
          list.appendChild(entry);
        }
      }  
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <strong>Your two items:</strong>
    <ol id="list">
    </ol>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I fixed: got rid of the function `listAdd` and moved the code directly into the `if` clause, renamed `test` as `list` (misnamed variable), and moved the script into the body so the html nodes exist when it runs.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE = html>
 <head>

 </head>
 
 <body>
  <strong>Your two items:</strong>
    <ol id="list">
    </ol>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var item1 = window.prompt("Enter first item:");
      if (item1 != null) {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item1));
          list.appendChild(entry);       
    }

    var item2 = window.prompt("Enter second item");
      if (item2 != null) {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item2));
          list.appendChild(entry);
      }  
  </script>
 </body>
```

Your code wraps a function in an if. That's not right - you are *declaring* the function there, not running it. The result is that nothing happens. You could improve the code a little by declaring the `listAdd` function first, then calling it after each prompt, passing in the parameter from the prompt.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. One question -- why did function {} mess the code up? Is it supposed to be used for another purpose?

Comment: It's how you declare a function to use later. It does not run the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the function and you mistakenly set `list.appendChild(entry)` instead of `test.appendChild(entry)` because we called the ordered list item id and set it to the `test` variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE=html>

<body>
  <strong>Your two items:</strong>
  <ol id="list" >
  </ol>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      var test = document.getElementById('list');
   var item1 = window.prompt("Enter first item:");
    var item2 = window.prompt("Enter second item");

     if (item1 != null ) {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item1));
          test.appendChild(entry);
   }
     if (item2 != null ) {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item2));
          test.appendChild(entry);
   }


</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
    var value1 = document.getElementById('list');
    var value1 = window.prompt("Enter first item:");
      if (value1 != null) {
        listAdd(value1);        
    }

    var value2 = window.prompt("Enter second item");
      if (value2 != null) {
        listAdd(value2);
      }
      
      
function listAdd(textValue) {
          var entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textValue));
          list.appendChild(entry);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE = html>
 <head>

 </head>
 
 <body>
  <strong>Your two items:</strong>
    <ol id="list">
    </ol>
 </body>
```

Created a generic function to add values in the List:
This is also used to reduce code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

This is one way

```
<body> 
  <ul id='myList'>
    <li> Item One </li>
  </ul>
<script>
    let myList = document.getElementById('myList');
    function makeUserLi(userPrompt){
      console.log(userPrompt)
            let userItem = document.createElement('li')
            userItem.innerText = userPrompt ?? 'no text given';
            myList.append(userItem);
    }
    makeUserLi(window.prompt('Add A List Item'))
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is a working codepen

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/miaklwalker/pen/xxwLxEm)